# Spot vars and functions with regex in mathematical formulas

Tags: regex, parsing, math

I am trying to get an array of **functions**, and an array of **variables** in any **mathematical formula** in **vanilla JS** :

A sample :

```
1+3*9/cos(4+2*x/6+pol)+
BDLIRE(longueur2)+2*8+sin(2)
+g()
```

For getting functions I use : `/([a-zA-Z]+)(?=[(])/gm`
https://regex101.com/r/fT3iM7/1

For getting vars I tried : `/([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]?)(?!\()/gm`
https://regex101.com/r/mG2fQ2/1

But as you can see it ignores last char of a match followed by a `(` char
So i'm a bit stuck with my regex to match variables.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use RegEx to parse arithmetic expressions, maybe you can, but you will have a flaky implementation and writing it WILL make you go bonkers.

You need to look into parsers. Check out PEG.js, it is an easy to use framework for writing parsers that compiles into JS, so it IS "vanilla" (Whatever you mean by that...):

http://pegjs.org/

Comment: Thanks i'll look forward into that, my taughs were that, i have a string mathematical operation, if i get functions and variables, i could have a scope with all vars and functions and use something like eval, or i don't know yet.

Comment: I'm using coffeescript, and it is for a dynamic form, so with a try - catch it seems a good plan.

Comment: I'll try to finish out a proto with the eval solution, as for the regex problem, i'll just get ```([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[(]?)``` so vars and functions separate them with and ```indexOf('(')```

This is just form a calculator form, so it may be oversized to use PEG.js, if it's not concluant i'll try this lib